# Extended JSP taglib

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts, taglib

Is there any extended JSP taglib available? Basically, because of project constraints, we're using a home-grown framework and working with JSPs. We want a taglib that will help us work easily with html forms and form elements and provide some sort of binding. Something like struts html tablib. I'm not sure if we can use the struts taglib standalone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I can provide for you is to use a retired tag library from jakarta.

It still works but it is no longer supported or maintained by them.

The link can be found [here](http://attic.apache.org/projects/jakarta-taglibs.html)

The one you will be interested in is the "[input](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jakarta/taglibs/deprecated/input/trunk/)" tag library which has tags for the following fields:

form
text
password
textarea
hidden
select
option
radio
checkbox

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem using Struts with appropriate JAR files in Web App lib folders (put all the Struts JARs in there)

Comment: The question regards using a taglib like the Struts taglib, with their homegrown framework.

Comment: Did you? "Can we use the Struts taglib **standalone**?" OP isn't asking if they can use Struts. They have a framework. They want a taglib they can use with that, that does binding. The Struts taglibs are not an appropriate choice because they're tightly-bound to the rest of the framework. JSP-based custom tags would be a better choice.

Comment: So you should have posted a different answer that might have read "you can't because they're too tightly coupled, but here's one you can". I think they can use the Struts taglib.

Comment: I posted a comment to that effect; it wasn't worth an answer. But you're simply not correct--both the S1 and S2 taglibs rely on underlying framework mechanics and classes--retrofitting would be silly.